# Creating a line graph using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

On the rows we have "purposes" and on the columns we have "grades".

I'm attempting to use ggplot2 to plot 14 separate line graphs (all overlayed on one graph). One for each type of "purpose".

On the x-axis will be the "grades" and on the y-axis will be the values in the cells which are percentages. How might I do this since the grades and purposes are not actually grouped together?

[image]

Comment: Please provide data as plain text, not images, so users can copy/paste.

Comment: I'm downvoting because we already asked you earlier in the same day to include data as plain text instead of as an image.  Please get into some good question-asking habits to help us help you.  If you edit your question as requested, I will replace my downvote with an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I took three purpose & grades to illustrate how to plot the lines on ggplot.

Data-set:

```
df <- data.frame(purpose = c("car", "credit card", "debt consolidation"),
                 a = c(26.64, 24.81, 14.04),
                 b = c(30.44, 35.27, 27.65),
                 c = c(23.93, 24.85, 29.06))
```

Convert the data.frame into a stacked form:

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
       gather(grade, val, a:c)
```

Plot line graphs:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(as.numeric(as.factor(grade)), val, colour=purpose)) + 
     geom_line() + 
     scale_x_continuous("Grades", breaks=1:3, labels=c("A", "B", "C"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your data consists of discrete categories (purposes and grades), so a line graph is not really appropriate as it implies continuous transition. Since the grades sum to 100% within each purpose, I think stacked bars is a better choice.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(purpose = c("car", "credit card", "debt consolidation"),
                        a = c(26.64, 24.81, 14.04),
                        b = c(30.44, 35.27, 27.65),
                        c = c(23.93, 24.85, 29.06),
                        d = c(11.66, 10.13, 16.96),
                        e = c(5.18, 3.88, 8.87),
                        f = c(1.79, 0.90, 2.80),
                        g = c(0.36, 0.16, 0.62))

df1 %>% 
  gather(grade, value, -purpose) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(purpose, value)) + 
    geom_col(aes(fill = grade)) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]